# Proof of bizarre form of Cavalieri's Principle?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, area

In a book I'm really enjoying, *The Irrationals* by Julian Havil, in Chapter 2 he mentions that John Wallis often used *Cavalieri's Principle*, which he explains.

However, he then says that "in modern terms" it can be stated in 2 dimensions as $$\int_0^1f(x)dx = \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{r=0}^Nf(r)}{M_N(N+1)}$$ where $M_N = \max\{ f(x) | x\in [0, N]\}$ and where $f(x)$ is a positive- and real-valued continuous function defined on the positive real axis,  without any justification.

I can see that this is an incredibly useful idea, but why on earth is it true?! Why would the values of $f$ attained arbitrarily far away from the interval $[0,1]$ (e.g. in the sum $\sum^N_{r=0}f(r)$ in as $N$ grows large) have any effect on the area under $f(x)$ on that interval?

Comment: This does not appear to be true.  Say $f(x)=|\,\sin(2\pi\,x)\,|$.  Then $f(r)=0$ for every $r\in \mathbb Z$, so the right hand limit is clearly $0$, but the integral is not $0$.  I expect the argument of $f(r)$ was meant to be something other than what you wrote.

Comment: No - the book gives examples of Wallis' derivations using this exact typesetting, so I don't know...

Comment: @lulu: If you want, I can add a quick example?

Comment: Well, I'd prefer that you show me what's wrong with my counterexample.

Comment: @lulu I agree, there's something strange because the left side looks at the values of f in $[0,1]$ but the right side looks at values outside of that interval, both in the sum in the numerator and in the definition of $M_N$.  Furthermore, you're saying "stated in 2 dimensions" but I don't see the second dimension afterwards

Comment: @MrFatzo  Exactly.  In fact, the right hand ignores all the values in $[0,1]$ other than the endpoints.  So just take any smooth pulse function with support in $[.25,.75]$, say.  Then I can make the left hand anything I want without having much of an effect on the right hand.

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing with either of you... I *said just that* in my question... I'm just as mystified...

Comment: As stated, there is no mystery at all.  The claim is simply false.  Either you or the original author have left off crucial assumptions.

Comment: I have been thinking about it and I believe it is supposed to be wrong. The mathematician working on this lived 1616-1703, so he may not have considered or encountered such functions as $sin(x)$. Moreover, the book is a "history of mathematics" book and shows more than once how people through the ages assume completely nonsensical ideas to be true.

Comment: @IskyMathews past mathematicians used different and often less-rigorous machinery, but they weren’t fools or cranks. I’d get dollars to donuts the error is due to the modern-day author, and not the ancient mathematician.

Comment: @IskyMathews The claim is unfortunately simply wrong in all ways imaginable (check for absolute convergence), and the reason for this is most likely a typo... happens all the time. Perhaps you could send a photo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isky, the equation as others have said, is simply wrong there's no way getting around it (e.g. test for (absolute) convergence). It is mostly likely a typo, but having read a review of the book:

'The book has a fair number of proofreading errors. Some sentences don't make any sense. There are some formatting errors in the equations. There are some occasional minor errors in the proofs, but they are geneally easy to correct. The proof that pi is transcendental contains a serious error, and it took some work for me to modify it to something correct'

Daniele

Answer (score 2):

What is true here is that $$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = \lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{r=0}^{N}\frac{f\left(\frac r{N+1}\right)}{N+1}$$when $f$ is continuous. This is just the definition of the Cauchy Integral. Riemann modified to allow for the interval sizes to vary and the points where the interval heights are measured to also vary. This allowed the requirement that $f$ be continuous to be relaxed.

Your version is evidently mistyped just in the fact that it is supposedly calculating the integral of $f(x)$ between $0$ and $1$ by using values of $f$ taken far away from that interval.

What the author was intending for this expression to be is unclear. I cannot see how it relates to Cavalieri's principle at all.

Answer (score 1):

For f(x)=5 , the LHS is $5$ and the RHS is $1$