# Does this limit become the definite integral $\int_0^1f(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855953/proof-of-bizarre-form-of-cavalieris-principle) question, I asked about "a version of Cavalieri's principle ... stated in modern terms" taken from Julian Havil's book *The Irrationals*, as it was mentioned for quite a short amount of time and without proof. It turned out that the idea was wrong in essentially all ways possible (it even failed on constant functions!).

Today, I wish to consider variants of it that might fix it. **My first question is: is it true that** $$\int_0^1f(x)dx = \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}f(\frac{i}{N})}{\max\{f(\frac{1}{m})|1\leq m\leq N\}(N+1)}$$

Comment: Just try some examples.  Take $f(n)=c$.  Then the numerator is $cN$, the max is $c$ , so we are taking the limit of $\frac {cN}{c(N+1)}$, and the limit is therefore $1$.

Comment: Yeah... I'm dumb. Sorry... :(

Comment: Have you any ideas as to what might fix it?

Comment: I truly don't get the point of the formula, nor what it has to do with Cavalieri.  If you drop the max term then it's more or less the usual Riemann definition of the integral.  But I really can't guess what the author had in mind.

Comment: Your problem is a special case of a Riemann sum

Comment: More particularly, with the max term removed , this is Cauchy's definition of the integral. The problem with it is that you have to require $f(x)$ to be continuous in order to do anything useful with it. Riemann developed his definition exactly so that restriction to continuous functions could be dropped.